# Oracle 11g: In PL/SQL is there any way to get info about inserted and updated rows after MERGE DML statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge, oracle11g, dml

I would like to know is there any way to receive information in PL/SQL how many rows have been updated and how many rows have been inserted while my PL/SQL script using MERGE DML statement.

Let's use Oracle example of merge described here: [MERGE example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#sthref9114)

This functionality is used in my function but also I'd like to log information how many rows has beed updated and how many rows have been inserted.

Comment: `SQL%ROWCOUNT` would tell you the number of rows merged, but I don't think you can get separate values for the inserts and updates. There's a [trick here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=220) though.

Comment: Sir, please post this as answer and I will accept this solution :)

Comment: Remember to have PK's or UNIQUE indexes on your merge condition columns of both tables to avoid errors while following the PACKAGE trick as referred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a not a built-in way to get separate insert and update counts, no. `SQL%ROWCOUNT` would tell you the number of rows merged, as you probably already know, but there is no equivalent to get separate values for the inserts and updates.

[This article by Adrian Billington](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=220) shows a way to get the information by including a function call in the merge, which might add a little overhead.

There's a similar, and perhaps simpler, trick from [MichaelS on the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/message/3453055#3453055), which I can't take any credit for at all either, of course. I'm tempted to reproduce it here but I'm not sure if that's allowed, but essentially it's using `sys_context` to maintain a count, in much the same way that Adrian's solution did with a package variable. I'd use that one, as it's cleaner and I think it's easier to follow and maintain.

Still perilously close to a link-only answer but I don't want to plagiarise others' work either...

Comment: Please review [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19159044/232279). Variant with triggers allows counting of deleted rows and makes query text more clear. Is any misleading in this solution?

Comment: this is also great approach but i can't define new triggers :/

Comment: Solution works, but seems to be dependent on query execution plan in generic hypothetical situation because of function calls is subject to optimization. At least Mighty Tom hates this variant :) [AskTom-1](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:122741200346595110#125700900346637534), [AskTom-2](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:35615502072484#795192300346797526)

Comment: @ThinkJet - also interesting, I hadn't thought about that aspect, and hadn't noticed it being mentioned anywhere in my brief search earlier. I don't think I'd expect a non-deterministic function to be optimised in a way that would matter, but I'm not going to argue with Tom! Still, I didn't take the credit, so I can't take the blame either - phew.

Answer (score 3):

Workarounds pointed by @AlexPoole works, but for me it's strange why don't count updates, inserts and even possible deletes by more natural way with triggers.

Suppose we have simple test table:

```
create table test_table (id number, col number)
```

Define simple package for counters

```
create or replace package pkg_test_table_counter as

  procedure reset_counter;

  procedure count_insert;
  procedure count_update;
  procedure count_delete;

  function get_insert_count return number;
  function get_update_count return number;
  function get_delete_count return number;

end;
```

... and package body:

```
create or replace package body pkg_test_table_counter as

  vUpdateCount number := 0;
  vInsertCount number := 0;
  vDeleteCount number := 0;

  procedure reset_counter is
  begin
    vUpdateCount := 0;
    vInsertCount := 0;
    vDeleteCount := 0;
  end;

  procedure count_insert is
  begin
    vInsertCount := vInsertCount + 1;
  end;

  procedure count_update is
  begin
    vUpdateCount := vUpdateCount + 1;
  end;

  procedure count_delete is
  begin
    vDeleteCount := vDeleteCount + 1;
  end;

  function get_insert_count return number is
  begin
    return vInsertCount;
  end;

  function get_update_count return number is
  begin
    return vUpdateCount;
  end;

  function get_delete_count return number is
  begin
    return vDeleteCount;
  end;

end;
```

To count number of rows during execution of single DML statement we need to reset it in before statement trigger

```
create or replace trigger trg_test_table_counter_reset 
  before insert or update or delete on test_table
begin
  pkg_test_table_counter.reset_counter;
end;
```

... and increment appropriate counter in trigger for each row:

```
create or replace trigger trg_test_table_counter_count 
  before insert or update or delete on test_table
  for each row
begin
  if inserting then 
    pkg_test_table_counter.count_insert;
  end if;
  if updating then 
    pkg_test_table_counter.count_update;
  end if;
  if deleting then 
    pkg_test_table_counter.count_delete;
  end if;
end;
```

So, after executing `MERGE` statement without additional tricks inside DML query text it's always possible to get exact number of affected rows:

```
select 
  pkg_test_table_counter.get_insert_count    insert_count,
  (
    pkg_test_table_counter.get_update_count
    -
    pkg_test_table_counter.get_delete_count
  )                                          update_count,
  pkg_test_table_counter.get_delete_count    delete_count
from dual
```

Note that delete operations also counted as updates for `MERGE` , but to keep package useful for another operations there are two separate counters.

**[<kbd>SQLFiddle test</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c102/5)**

Comment: Interesting. Needs more thought ahead of time though as you'd have to have the triggers in place before you thought about the merge (don't want to run DDL ad hoc as it'll commit, maybe?); whereas you could just tack the other workarounds onto an existing query, but that might be more appropriate depending on final use. Triggers seem more heavy-handed to me, but just my opinion. (Your `trg_test_table_counter_count` trigger has two `if inserting` clauses, by the way, though I'm not sure why that doesn't affect the result - noticed when trying it with simple insert/update/delete statements).

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you for review and pointing on error (corrected)! Of course this solution not a choice if you need to generate tables ad hoc, but may be useful in static environment. In other words for me it seems to be a more "software-design-way" than a "database-administration-way" in  case of `sys_context` usage.  By the way variant with `sys_context` needs DDL too to create  `set_client_info` function.

Comment: Both the workarounds need DDL, but only once, not per table. That's the bit that puts me off, other than that I like it *8-)