# Get a specific output for Oracle MERGE statement: Get different output for different clauses

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For the below mentioned query:

```
MERGE INTO bonuses D
   USING (SELECT employee_id, salary, department_id FROM employees
   WHERE department_id = 80) S
   ON (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01
     DELETE WHERE (S.salary > 8000)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.employee_id, D.bonus)
     VALUES (S.employee_id, S.salary*.01)
     WHERE (S.salary <= 8000);
```

I need to get the ID of the row only in case when the row has either been updated or inserted and NULL incase the row has been deleted. Would it be possible to achieve the same? Basically is there a way to know that a particular row has been updated or a new row has been inserted using the MERGE query.

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19156418/266304) Might be able to extend the approaches to counting to get the IDs of the affected rows instead; e.g. adding IDs to a collection instead of just incrementing a counter.

Comment: Makes perfect sense- thanks for pointing to the appropriate link! well, thought must be some trivial way of doing the same- but apparently proved wrong everyday! :)